# Building 2 jars with different source with Maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I am trying to build 2 jars from 1 java project.  The 2 jars would have the exact same source EXCEPT at build time one would build with a boolean variable set to True and one would build with that same boolean variable set to False.

Example:

Jar 1 would have all the same source except in 1 java file it would have:

```
public static final boolean ENABLE_TOAST = True;
```

Jar 2 would have all the same source except in that same java file it would have:

```
public static final boolean ENABLE_TOAST = False;
```

I am relatively new to Maven and Ant and I had the idea of using the maven-replacer-plugin.  However, I cannot find anyone who has done something like this before.

Comment: Could this be done with a properties file instead hard coded in the project's source code. The property file could even be embedded in the jar itself. The reason is that Maven has the ability to filter files as they get copied to a jar. Munging source with Maven is very difficult, and I would never recommend munging source code via the build process. Just too risky.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to create three properties files:

1. app.properties
2. app.properties.test.environment
3. app.properties.prod.environment

2) and 3) have the different settings for each environment (i.e. ENABLE_TOAST = false for prod and true for test)

The application, of course, only uses app.properties

At build time, I replace app.properties with the contents of the correct environment (2 or 3)

In ANT, I have two targets each with a copy file command with an overwrite flag set to true.

I'm sure MAVEN has a similar feature (too busy to look it up ATM)

hope this helps

Comment: With this method, how would you change the java file's code using the properties file as the properties file is not java code?  Also, at build time what code would you use to build both jars at the same time?

Comment: The Java code would change to `ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle( <path>\app.properties );
public static final boolean ENABLE_TOAST = res.getString("enable.toast");`;

Comment: Then your app.properties files would contain the following: `enable.toast = true`

Comment: if using ANT, you can build both jars by calling a target that jars your code two times with differnet jar file names (i.e. environment name in the file: app-test.jar or app-prod.jar)
`<target name="build-all" depends="... compile, ... <list them here>">
  <jar destfile="app-test.jar" basedir="..." />
  <jar destfile="app-prod.jar" basedir="..." />
</target>`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not an standard practice and recommended also, you should make your code free from these types of practices.

Best solution for these types of problems is externalize as many as property we can and most importantly try to avoid to make these properties file as part of jar. Store them somewhere in your server.

I can give you a very simple example , in our application we have different database connection details for different environment like Dev , QA , UAT etc , so there instead of integrating all these things in the java code , we provided all those values in the properties file and with the help of java code we are reading those properties during application startup time.

Thanks